# OUTER JOIN from different column names to same column

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, outer-join

I am trying to select columns from different tables (the columns have different name) and use an outer join to get them in a single table. How do I do this?
(I am using sqlplus)
Here is an example:

Table a:

```
a.NAME1        a.NAME2      a.RATING
Jack           Sparrow      4
```

Table b:

```
b.FIRSTNAME    b.LASTNAME   b.RATING
Jack           Sparrow      7
```

Table 3:

```
c.F_NAME       c.L_NAME     c.RATING
Jack           Sparrow      6
```

I would like a table like this:

```
NAME            RATING
Jack            4
                7
                6
```

I tried this code

```
SELECT
    a.NAME1 AS NAME,
    b.FIRSTNAME AS NAME,
    c.F_NAME AS NAME,
    a.RATING AS RATING,
    b.RATING AS RATING,
    c.RATING AS RATING
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN (b
CROSS JOIN c)
    ON (a.NAME1 = b.FIRSTNAME
    AND a.NAME1 = c.F_NAME);
```

But that didn't work. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Are you trying to get 1 row with three different columns for ratings?  Or three rows?

Comment: I am trying to get three different rows for the same column but I understand that outer join will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not sound like you want to join the tables at all.  If you joined three tables each with 1 row, you would end up with a result set that had a single row and many columns.  Since your goal is to end up with three rows of data, you would want to use a `union all`

```
SELECT a.name1, a.rating 
  FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.firstname, b.rating 
  FROM b
UNION ALL
SELECT c.f_name, c.rating 
  FROM c
```

If you want to eliminate duplicate rows, use a `union` rather than a `union all`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.NAME1, a.NAME2, a.RATING, b.RATING, c.RATING
from a 
left outer join b on b.FIRSTNAME = a.NAME1 and b.LASTNAME = a.NAME2
left outer join c on c.F_NAME = a.NAME1 and c.L_NAME = a.NAME2
```

Comment: I tried that, it return three different columns for ratings.